# LXDE desktop installation

Tags: software-installation, configuration, lxde

How do I install the LXDE desktop environment? I have it installed in Ubuntu, but cannot figure out how to install it so that it can be used.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. You ask about how to install lxde in the first sentence but then say you have it installed in the second sentence. Could you please edit your question to explain what exactly your problem is?

Comment: May be, you have installed LXDE package, but did not install lubuntu-core? In this case, only lxde desktop will be available

Answer (score 0):

The LXDE page in the Ubuntu Software Center contains 5 useful add-ons for LXDE including GUI login manager for LXDE (lxdm) and Easy-Mode launcher for netbook (lxlauncher). The LXDE add-ons can be installed by putting a check mark in the checkbox to the left of each add-on and then clicking on the **Install** button.

There are many possibilities for customization in the LXDE desktop including the package used to manage the internet connection, the LXDE Panel, the Desktop wallpaper and icon fonts. Take a look at this illustrated tutorial: [How to Customize the LXDE Desktop](http://www.linuceum.com/Distros/osDesktopConfigLXDE.php).

Answer (score 0):

On the Ubuntu Log In screen you'll see the Ubuntu icon besides (to the right of) your username and on top of the password box, click on the icon and then you'll see the different desktop environments available. Choose the one you prefer to use.